# browse through branch refs making use '/' (forward slash) grouping

Tags: git, branch

I have two parts o the following question.

***GENERAL***:
    Including a `/` (forward slash) within the name of a branch puts the head of that branch within a directory specified by the path as interpreted using the `/`.

e.g. The head of a branch named `Category-1/Ref-1` wil be named `Ref-1` and stored in `./.git/refs/heads/Category-1/` as `Ref-1`.

I will refer to this sort of 'branch directory' as **Branch Pseudo Folder (BPF)**

***PART 1 -***

I would like to have something like the dos `dir` command or linux `ls` command for listing all the refs in a particular BPF.

***PART 2 -***

For such a command, i would like to configure Tab-completion to work as it works when typing normal System paths.
    Also, I would like to configure a similar tab configuration for other functions that require ref names e.g. `git checkout`

e.g - Assume the command is named `git branch-ls`. Also. assume that the following 4 branch heads exist.

```
Cooling/AC
Cooling/Fridge

Heating/Heater
Heating/Microwave
```

Now, I would like the following behavior.

```
git branch-ls Hea[tab]
```

Should complete to `git branch-ls Heating/` and a further tab should complete to the complete ref name. Note that this is unlike the working of branch name completion as in `checkout`.

Also,

```
git branch-ls Heating/
```

should list all the refs in the above BPF. i.e. Its output should be of the form

```
Heater
Microwave
```